# MFMessageComposeViewController having the message body repeated twice

Tags: ios, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

When using the following code to setup an in-app SMS message using the MFMessageComposeViewController:

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    // Add Cocos view & stop anims
    [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:self.view];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];

    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    controller.body = @"TEST";
    controller.recipients = nil;
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;

    // Cocos window view present
    [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] window] addSubview:controller.view];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{NSLog(@"test open");}];


}
```

The view appears correctly but the message body text is appearing twice. In the editable text field it has 'TEST', then another 'TEST' again on the following line.

I've tried adding a title and using various different messages but I'm always getting the message body appearing twice. I also checked if the code is only being called more than once, but it isn't.

Anyone any ideas?

(Xcode 5.0.1, iPhoneOS 7.0 SDK, testing on an iPhone 5)

Comment: can you paste full code which you said "... etc..."?

Comment: added... it was the Cocos view stuff. The window itself is appearing fine.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else experiencing this, I found that adding the controller view to the window BEFORE setting the body text fixed the issue.

Like so:

```
if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];

    MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];

    // ** Add the view BEFORE setting the body text... **
    [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] window] addSubview:controller.view];

    [controller setRecipients:nil];
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [controller setBody:message];

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES ];
}
```

With this code, the body text is not duplicated in the SMS.